# Are Object methods passed by reference or value to a global variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have been trying to figure out how can a method of an object be passed by value to a global variable but have been unable to do so.
I have passed an object method to unboundGetX (it should be passed by reference)
but after changing the object method later after assignment, the value stored inside variable doesn't change.

So are methods of object passed by value and not by reference?

Please help me on this.

```js
const module = {
    x: 42,
    getX: function() {
        console.log(this);
        return this.x;
    }
};
  
let unboundGetX = module.getX;

module.getX = function () {
    console.log("hello");
    return 10;
}

console.log(module.getX());
console.log(unboundGetX());
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of thinking about variables (*all* variables) is that they contain *pointers* to things in memory. With this:

```
const module = {
    x: 42,
    getX: function() {
        console.log(this);
        return this.x;
    }
};
let unboundGetX = module.getX;
```

`unboundGetX` now points to the same function in memory that `module.getX` points to.

If you reassign:

```
module.getX = function () {
```

`module.getX` now points to a different function (one that was just created), while `unboundGetX` keeps pointing to the original function.

The exact same behavior occurs if `getX` is a primitive, not a function (which might make it easier to understand the concept initially).

```js
const module = {
    getX: 'foo'
};
  
const foo = module.getX;

module.getX = 'bar';

console.log(module.getX);
console.log(foo);
```